# HTML 5 video tag and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have the following code, I wanted to fade the video in over eight seconds it works fine except it's only the tag that fades in (the controls). The video frame sequence starts off at frame one without any fade while the controls are still fading up. How do I bind the fade to both the video tag and the actual media so both image and controls fade up / or down?

```
function assets(){
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 8s linear 0s";
    elem.style.opacity = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You might want to play with adding some kind of overlay with an opacity transition.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like

```
$('#video video').bind('STATE', function(){
   $(this).parent().fadeOut()
})
```

Comment: How would I write this in Vanilla Javascript - for sake of consistency...